# SolrCloud Timeout issue when using Collection API

Tags: apache-zookeeper, weblogic12c, solrcloud, timeoutexception, broken-pipe

I'm using **solrcloud 4.10.2 deployed on weblogic 12c cluster with zookeeper 3.4.6 on Oracle Linux 6.4**.

I have 5 zk servers and 6 solr instances(weblogic server instances).

zk servers are distributed across 4 separate servers and the 6 solr servers are distributed across 4 physical servers.

Zookeeper and solr servers are running without any issue. (I can login to Solr Admin and can see cloud tab)

The problem comes when I trying to create collection or doing any kind of execution related to Collection API.

I’m always getting below **timeout exception** on Solr logs.

Same issue when using curl command.

> null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: createcollection the collection time out:180s
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleResponse(CollectionsHandler.java:368)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleResponse(CollectionsHandler.java:320)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleCreateAction(CollectionsHandler.java:486)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleRequestBody(CollectionsHandler.java:148)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
>       at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.handleAdminRequest(SolrDispatchFilter.java:729)
>       at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:267)
>       at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:207)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3367)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
>       at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>       at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>       at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)
>       at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
>
> null:java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
>       at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
>       at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
>       at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
>       at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
>       at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:487)
>       at weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer$NIOOutputStream.writeInternal(NIOSocketMuxer.java:1064)
>       at weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer$NIOOutputStream.write(NIOSocketMuxer.java:983)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.writeChunkTransfer(ChunkOutput.java:606)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.writeChunks(ChunkOutput.java:571)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.flush(ChunkOutput.java:459)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.CharsetChunkOutput.flush(CharsetChunkOutput.java:301)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutputWrapper.flush(ChunkOutputWrapper.java:188)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletOutputStreamImpl.flush(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:126)
>       at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
>       at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
>       at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
>       at org.apache.solr.util.FastWriter.flush(FastWriter.java:137)
>       at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.writeResponse(SolrDispatchFilter.java:766)
>       at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.handleAdminRequest(SolrDispatchFilter.java:736)
>       at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:267)
>       at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:207)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3367)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
>       at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>       at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>       at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)
>       at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?